Pyinstaller "skipping data collection for module 'sqlite-utils' as it is not a package."
I am creating an application with pyqt6, and one of the pages have:
import subprocess
# Create .bd file from csv
subprocess.run(["sqlite-utils", "insert", self.path + "/datasette/dm4_images.db", "dm4_images", self.path + "/datasette/dm4_images.csv", "--csv"], 
                            shell = True)

When I try to generate an executable with pyinstaller, it doesn't recognize sqlite-utils as a package, even if I manually add it to the .spec file. My .spec file is currently:
import os

sqlite_utils_binary = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'Scripts', 'sqlite-utils.exe')

datas = [('icons/*.svg', 'icons'), ('icons/*.png', 'icons'), ('icons/*.ico', 'icons'), ('detectron2Files/*.yaml', 'detectron2Files'), ('detectron2Files/*.pkl', 'detectron2Files'), (sqlite_utils_binary,'.')]

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['main_window.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[(sqlite_utils_binary, '.')],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=['sqlite-utils'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='TEMapp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['icons\\blue-microscope.ico'],
)

The warning while building the .exe is:
7919 WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'sqlite-utils' as it is not a package.
7919 WARNING: collect_dynamic_libs - skipping library collection for module 'sqlite-utils' as it is not a package.
Then if I try to use it, I have on the shell:
'sqlite-utils' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Anyone knows how I can fix it?
I've also tried to use https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib, and create a file inside stdhooks 'hook-sqlite_utils.py':
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all("sqlite-utils") 

Then: pyinstaller main.py --collect-all "sqlite-utils"
